# Unable to run ckanext-qa extension

Tags: config, ckan

I'm using CKAN as my open data portal and have successfully installed CKAN Quality Assurance Extension according to instructions at https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-qa/. I'm currently facing some problem with this step:

> This step can be performed by running the associated paster command
> from the ckanext-qa directory.

```
$ paster qa update|clean [package name/id] --config=<path to ckan config file>
```

I am getting this error:

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-qa-master$ paster qa update|clean --config=/etc/ckan/default
No command 'clean' found, did you mean:
 Command 'uclean' from package 'svn-buildpackage' (universe)
 Command 'clear' from package 'ncurses-bin' (main)
clean: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-qa-master/ckanext/qa/commands.py", line 50, in command
    self._load_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 91, in _load_config
    conf = self._get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 86, in _get_config
    raise AssertionError('Config filename %r does not exist.' % self.filename)
AssertionError: Config filename '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-qa-master/development.ini' does not exist.
```

My ckanext-qa directory is `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-qa-master` and my ckan config file is located at `/etc/ckan/default`. Did I run the command correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The command that you have run has 2 mistakes in it. First of all "update|clean" stands for "update or clean". Also, you didn't the specify the correct config file path. See the correct update and clean commands below:

```
paster qa update --config=/etc/ckan/default/development.ini
paster qa clean --config=/etc/ckan/default/development.ini
```

Additionally, there are 2 ways to run extension specific paster commands:

1. Navigate to ckanext-qa directory and execute the command:

   paster qa update --config=/etc/ckan/default/development.ini
2. Explicitly specify the extension name and then run the command

   paster --plugin=ckanext-qa qa update --config=/etc/ckan/default/development.ini